# Some questions about backup kiwi-tcms database

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I try to backup my kiwi tcms data following steps on web http://kiwitcms.org/blog/atodorov/2018/07/30/how-to-backup-docker-volumes-for-kiwi-tcms/. Some question need help.

1. Which type datas stored on kiwi_uploads? Shall I also use command "docker volume rm kiwi_uploads" then restore it? Did same as Backing up the database.
2. Some errors occurs as below when restore kiwi_uploads using "cat uploads.tar | docker exec -i kiwi_web /bin/tar -x". But even error occurs, login and find previous data ok, such as plan, runs, test case...Of cause, I restore kiwi_db_data successfully.

   `cat uploads.tar | docker exec -i kiwi_web /bin/tar -x
   /bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
   /bin/tar: Skipping to next header
   /bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

3."cat database.json | docker exec -i kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py loaddata --format json -". No any parameter behind last -? missing or just as this.

Comment: Unfortunately, posts here on Stack Overflow can only contain one question, and should avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. Please [edit] this so it only asks one question.

Comment: OK，I wii pay more attention to this. But this time, my question is just about one thing. I listed as 1, 2, 3 just make it more clearly. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) kiwi_uploads is for all files that are uploaded (or attached) to documents like Test Plan, Test Case, etc.

The instructions in the blog should work for you. Usually there's no need to remove the volume but if you are restoring everything it doesn't really matter.

2) For the errors you have
`/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive`

so whatever file you ended up with is not a tar archive and everything else fails.

3) The last `-` means to read the input data from stdin. You have to copy the backup and restore commands verbatim.

All commands are designed to be executed from a Linux host. I don't have access to a Windows or Mac OS box so I don't know if they will work there at all.

Comment: OK，when asking this question, I run docker on my Mac OS.
Today I install parallels on my Mac, install Ubuntu 16.04 in this virtual machine. Then run kiwitcms on docker container follow docs. But same error occurs when restore uoloads.tar. Ubuntu installed in virtual machine has some difference with pure ubuntu? Any comments?

parallels@parallels-vm:~/works/kiwi_backup$ cat uploads.tar | docker exec -i kiwi_web /bin/tar -x
/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: I ask one workmate, says maybe the tar backup file has some problem? So error occurs when restoring?

Comment: @cj chen unless you provide the exact steps which you used to create the tar archive in the first place and the corresponding logs I can't tell what went wrong. Clearly the .tar file is currupted so doing anything else after that is pointless.

Comment: Uploaded files can easily be backed up with:
docker exec -it kiwi_web /bin/tar -cP /var/kiwi/uploads > uploads.tar
and then restored:
cat uploads.tar | docker exec -i kiwi_web /bin/tar -x

I just follow the docs on kiwitcms org web. Some mistake in backup command? I just doubt. First, -cP? this parameter is for tar and not find P parameter for tar. Second, /var/kiwi/uploads, is this path in container? I go into container via docker exec -it kiwi_web /bin/bash, no kiwi folder in var. I only find this, /Kiwi/uploads

Kindly have a double check?

Comment: At some point in time /var/kiwi/uploads was changed to /Kiwi/uploads. You probably executed the command against non-existing directory which resulted in the broken tar file.

Comment: OK，I find document on kiwitcms blog has be updated now. I tried just now, and seems work OK. Thx for solving my problem.